# Negative Sub Range error

Tags: delphi, set

I was wondering if it's possible to declare

```
Value1, Value2: Set of -2..-1;
```

I'm getting a compile error: [DCC Error] ShowUtils.pas(98): E2028 Sets may have at most 256 elements.

By my maths that's 2 elements -2 and -1 why does the compiler think there's more than 256?

using Delphi 2007

Comment: A couple of solutions. Use set of 1..2 and test things like `-i in Value1`. Or make these special values a dedicated enumerated type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error appears because, the ordinal values of the bounds of the set must be between 0 and 255. so **you cannot use negative numbers in a set**,  Additionally you can check the documentation about the compiler error [`E2028 Sets may have at most 256 elements (Delphi)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2028_Sets_may_have_at_most_256_elements_%28Delphi%29)

Comment: ah, i was hoping for some compiler trick that just sorted out an offset to put it into that range